# Install of Groovy on Ubuntu 12.10 Problem

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ubuntu-quantal, yaml-cpp, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I upgraded from U12.04 where I was using ROS-F to U12.10 and then attempted to install ROS-G.

It seems that there is a conflict between libyaml-cpp-dev and yaml-cpp which needs to have a 'conflicts' added to the .deb package.  (Error Below)

Unpacking libyaml-cpp-dev (from .../libyaml-cpp-dev_0.3.0-1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libyaml-cpp-dev_0.3.0-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/include/yaml-cpp/aliasmanager.h', which is also in package yaml-cpp 0.2.7-5precise-20120502-0513-+0000
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libyaml-cpp-dev_0.3.0-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

This error happens now whenever I try to use apt-get and I'm unable to install or remove packages from my system. Help Please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51806/install-of-groovy-on-ubuntu-12.10-problem/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2013-01-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-09**:
Also, make sure your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list was updated correctly for the new Ubuntu version.

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-01-09**:
I updated many times without success. Also, the sources appear correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same conflict. The conflict was actually between yaml-cpp and libyaml-cpp-dev.

```
sudo apt-get remove ^ros*
sudo apt-get remove --purge yaml-cpp
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full
```

resolved my issue.

---

Originally posted by [philotuxo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4175/philotuxo/) with karma: 46 on 2013-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2